# Detectar tecla BORRAR para eliminar CHAR en Javascript - [event.code - event.which - event.keyCode ]

Tags: javascript, eventos, keypressevent, onkeyup

Estoy intentando detectar el carácter de borrar para saber cuando un usuario pulsa en la tecla borrar.
Para detectar todas las demás teclas lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
function newLine(e){
 if(e.code == "Space"){
      console.log("Has pulsado la barra espaciadora");
   }else if(e.code == "Enter"){
      console.log("Has pulsado Enter");
   }
}
</script>
```

Consigo detectar todas las teclas como Space o Enter con e.code pero por lo visto con la tecla borrar no funciona.
Pone en la documentación la plabra Delete pero lo he probado y no funciona, no sé que puede pasar.
A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

Gracias de ante mano !! Saludos !!!

Comment: ¿Borrar o retroceso?  La tecla Borrar es Supr, y la tecla retroceso es <- (solo por si acaso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio podrías detectarla sin inconvenientes utilizando el key o el code por ejemplo del evento.

En el siguiente ejemplo con la tecla suprimir o delete (que se detecta como Delete) se remueve la primer letra del string, con Backspace se elimina el último caracter del string.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("h1");
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  const currentValue = text.textContent;
  switch (e.key) {
    case "Backspace":
      text.textContent = currentValue.slice(0, -1);
      break;
    case "Delete":
      text.textContent = currentValue.substring(1);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Texto de prueba</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En cuanto a los eventos podrías utilizar tanto keypress como keydown, esto varía en función de las necesidades, el evento keydown se ejecuta siempre que se presiona una tecla y antes de que el navegador procese el caracter, el keypress se ejecuta después del keydown cuando se presiona una tecla que produce un valor y también antes de que el navegador procese el caracter.

Comment: Buenas ! Tienes razón puedo capturar la tecla con Backspace pero no me funcionaba porque estaba utlizando "keypress" en vez de "keydown", con "keypress" por lo visto no funciona. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda !!

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione, quedo a las órdenes!

Answer (score 1):

No sé exactamente qué quieres hacer, pero en chrome esto funciona perfectamente para detectar todas las teclas:

```js
function checkPressedKey(event) {
  // Imprimimos la tecla que se ha pulsado. Funciona con cualquier tecla, incluyendo Control, Shift...
  // Incluso funciona con la tecla de windows :)
  console.log(event.key);
  // Si es el retroceso, mostrar alerta
  if(event.key === "Backspace") 
    alert("estás borrando!");
}
```

```html
<input onkeydown="checkPressedKey(event)"></input>
```

Lo más recomendado es usar el atributo [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) del evento keypress, como ves hace que sea muy sencillo.

Comment: Buenas ! Si, utilizando "Backspace" se puede capturar la tecla de borrar pero la cosa era que estaba utilizando "keypress" en vez de "keydown", por lo visto con "keypress" no la captura. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda !!